# How can I place a phone call programmatically from a Mac app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, skype, osx-yosemite, continuity

With the advent of handoff/continuity in OS X Yosemite, I was hoping there would be an API for this.  I can't find one Googling.  Alternatively, is there a way to open designated phone call making app like Skype to place a call?  I've seen links on web pages to phone numbers that auto-open my Skype app.  Is that the way to do it - with some HTML embedded in my Mac app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the same "tel:5555555555" URL syntax that you use on mobile platforms.  So, for example to call the number 5555555555 you can do:

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "tel:5555555555") {
    NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().openURL(url)
}
```